# Authblk style file using but I can't able to find out the required output

Tags: horizontal-alignment, links, authblk

I am using the `authblk` package. But I can't able to find out the output for below mentioned problems.

I am using the below mentioned logic. If the same affiliation is repeated different author like see below mentioned coding (Author 2, Author 3) the address counter is not working properly like (address 1, address 2).

I need a output author affiliation number is not affected to the `\affil` command. `\affil` is counted like 1, 2, 3, ...

I need a another requirement each author have a link. If I move the mouse (Author 1) the corresponding hyperlink like (http://www.canon.org/peole/520456) hand signal viewed in the PDF output. If I click the author the link is open an web browser.

Kindly advise the solutions.

```
\author[aff={1}]{Author 1}

\author[aff={2}]{Author 2}

\author[aff={2}]{Author 3}

\author[aff={3}]{Author 4}

\affil{address1}

\affil{address2}

\affil{address3}
```

[image: Author image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\author{Author 1}
\affil{address1}

\author{Author 2}    
\author{Author 3}
\affil{address2}

\author{Author 4}
\affil{address3}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\title{Bad superscript with authblk / xltxtra}
\author{Author 1}
\affil{address1}

\author{Author 2}    
\author{Author 3}
\affil{address2}

\author{Author 4}
\affil{address3}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]